# Repairing a Bosch 400W mixer

Tags: electrical, repair

I broke my mixer a few weeks ago while preparing soup -- I guess I went a bit too hard on the motor, and a fuse must have burnt. This is exactly the model shown below over there, except that it's 400W, not 600W: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSnnk.jpg

Is there any hope I can repair this by myself? If so, how exactly, and will it be worth the effort (in particular, will this be cheaper than buying a new one?)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Generally, appliance-related questions which are considered on-topic are concerning permanently installed appliances such as dishwashers and ranges.

Comment: Unfortunately those smaller mixers are not built for ease of servicing.  Generally they have a built in fuse which automatically resets after the motor cools off, but they also include a thermal fuse inside the motor windings as a backup in case the resettable fuse fails, or the motor overheats for some other reason.  This fuse is not only one-time-use, but it's embedded in the motor windings and even if it's easy to get to, it's not easy to replace.  If it is instead a problem with the motor controller, then finding the problem and fixing it is not going to be trivial.

Comment: So, unfortunately, it's unlikely that you'll be able to repair it.  Call up Bosch, even if it's out of warranty.  Sometimes they choose to replace bad products beyond the warranty period.  If it's out of warranty and they won't replace it, then go ahead and disassemble it and inspect it - it's not as if you're going to break it worse, and you may find the problem is visible and easy to fix.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your credit cards, or the store you purchased it from may have built-in extended warranties for such items.  Might be worth checking into.

Answer (score 3):

On topic or no - rebuilding a hand blender like that is generally an exercise in futility.

Based on my experience trying to fix small items like that - replacement parts for small appliances like that are non-existent.